# How to implement Line of Crayon texture in React Konva

Tags: react-konva, konva

[image]

I am creating a free draw app using konva. What method should I use to draw lines with a crayon texture like the photo above? This is the Line code I use.

```
<Line
    id={line.id}
    x={line.x}
    y={line.y}
    points={line.points}
    stroke={line.color}
    strokeWidth={line.width}
    tension={0.5}
    lineCap="round"
    lineJoin="round"
    perfectDrawEnabled={false}
    globalCompositeOperation="source-over"
/>
```